# Protractor/webdriver-manager error: "Cannot get automation extension"

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I am running protractor tests, and within the last couple days started getting this error:

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot get automation extension 
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
```

After some research, I tried updating protractor but I was already on the latest version (5.1.1). I checked to see if my chromedriver and chrome version are compatible and it looks like they are. I also updated my webdriver-manage to 12.0.4 but I still have the same problem.

-My chrome version is: 57.0.2987.133 (Official Build) (64-bit)

-protractor is: 5.1.1

-webdriver-manager is: 12.0.4

-chromedriver version:  2.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3508

According to the comment from "JimmyKane" installing chromedriver v2.28 and removing the browser.manage().window().setSize() fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's any way to be able to keep browser.mange().window().setSize()? Because I need that for a few tests

Comment: @John123, when you are on webdriver-manager version 12.0.4 and you do an update you will get ChromeDriver 2.29, that is the latest version that supports Chrome 57. That should also work with the `browser.manage().window().setSize() `

Comment: @John123 Actually, I just updated the chromedriver to v2.28 and I used the browser.manage().window().setSize() in my test and it still worked.

Comment: @Brine interesting...so you are using Linux and getting the `WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot get automation extension` error with chromedriver 2.29 (which is now the current version)?

Comment: Oh, actually, no. I'm debugging and `webdriver-manager` was still pulling 2.27. Now when specifying it in my conf, 2.29/chrome 57, on ubuntu 16.04, I'm getting `WebDriverError: chrome not reachable` :) Fun times!